# Implement reminder service in Event Driven architecture in Azure

Tags: azure, events, azure-functions, event-driven

We are building a workflow, when the workflow starts, few steps are executed i.e.

1. Create/Open proposal  - Takes around 30 sec
2. Perform calculations - Takes around 90 sec
3. Send notification to user(s) to approve or reject - Takes around 10 sec

As 4th step we will have to wait for X no. of days and send out reminder to user to approve/reject the proposal if it is not approved/rejected.

We are planning to implement 1-3 using event driven architecture. At the end of step#3 we are thinking of writing a record to DB. step#4 will be developed as Azure function which runs at regular intervals to sweep DB table for pending notifications and send out notifications to users.

I would like to understand if there are other better implementations of step#4 in native cloud design on Azure.

Please suggest me if there is a better way to implement end to end flow other than event driven design

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Functions with Durable Framework and Timers, in order to send the reminder

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers?tabs=csharp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=csharp

Comment: Thanks for your input. 

Is there any other way to achieve other than using durable functions?

Do you think is it an anti-pattern if I use Lambda function which sweeps DB table at regular intervals to send out reminder(s). 

PS: I might need to send multiple reminders if user did not approve/reject.

Comment: I think there's some way using Logic Apps, but I've never did that way

Comment: With logic Apps we are limited with customization so we have ruled out logic apps option.

Thanks for your inputs